# How to delete row in database with no ids

Tags: android, sqlite

I have an idless database in my application. How can I delete any of the rows? My database code is as follows:

```
mydb=Nickname.this.openOrCreateDatabase("private", 0, null);
            mydb.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS numbers(nickname varchar,number INT(13))");
```

Anyone know how it is possible?

```
mydb=Clear.this.openOrCreateDatabase("private", 0, null);
            mydb.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS numbers(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,nickname varchar,number INT(13))");
mydb.execSQL("DELETE FROM numbers WHERE id='=?' AND number='"+num+"'");

//num is string which contains which number i wish to delete
```

Comment: make nickname primary key so that u can delete exactly one row

Comment: `mydb.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS numbers(nickname text primary key,number integer)");` try this??

Comment: mydb.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS numbers(id text primary key auto_increment not null,nickname varchar,number integer)"); ..................is it correct?

Comment: id should be integer, if nicknames wont repeat in your application make it primary key

Comment: Can u please give some additional information on how you want to delete nicknames??

Comment: my application for hide messages...once i will added the number...in future i want to delete my table row comletly....nickname and number also....i'll update my main code...please check it

Comment: Well Dipin, You are storing nickname of user and his no right?? then probably number must be primary key, deletion of a record must be based on number. Nicknames may repeat but numbers wont.

Comment: try this `mydb.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS numbers(number integer primary key, nickname text not null)");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [SQLDatabase](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#delete%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29) object has a delete method. public int delete (String table, String whereClause, String[] whereArgs)

```
mydb.delete(TABLE, "nickname = "+ DatabaseUtils.sqlEscapeString(name), null);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mydb.execSQL("DELETE FROM your_db.your_table WHERE  <write your SQL conditions here> ");
```

Comment: You mean    mydb.execSQL("DELETE private.numbers WHERE  nick="<any row value which is to be wish to delete>" ");

Comment: yes, my answer was generic. If you want to delete all rows where nick is equal to 'bob':  DELETE FROM private.numbers WHERE nick='bob';  BTW i missed 'from' originally in my answer, i've updated that.

Comment: i want to delete ony one row bro

Comment: you can give you rows a unique field by adding a primary key to your table schema.  set it to be an auto incrementing index.  Then when you delete, reference that key in your delete statement.

Comment: Run this query only once:  mydb.execSQL("alter table private.numbers add id int(11) primary key auto_increment not null;");

Comment: you mean    alter table private.numbers add id int(11) primary key auto_increment not null;    mydb.execSQL("DELETE FROM numbers WHERE  number='"+num+"'");

Comment: Depends...  IF num is a unique value for that field for all rows, then that would work.  If not, it will delete all rows with the field having the value =num.  The alter table statement is supposed to give you a row ID or primary index that is unique for all rows.   After you add that key, look up what the value of that key is for the row you want to delete.  Then run your delete query like DELETE FROM numbers WHERE id='"+theRowID+"' AND number='"+num+"

Comment: yea.  you only need to run it once.  FYI you run it twice, it'll probably throw an error saying something like 'field id already exists...'

Comment: Not sure I get your error.  I just ran this query to do something simimlarand it should work for you-  ALTER TABLE `numbers` ADD COLUMN `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT  AFTER `number` , ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`) , ADD UNIQUE INDEX `id_UNIQUE` (`id` ASC) ;